# xslt:1.0 - Using xslt how to take values from regex and create new element

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

This is my XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <update-this>
    <document name="http://blah">
     <amount>015-39</amount>
    <shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
    <url>http://www.blah.com/my-spade-clothing-11176/487/878765?dn_hhe=mylist-_-nothing-_-nothing-_-nothing</url>
    <size>11.5 D</size>
    <price>100.00 USD</price>
    <stock>present in stock </stock>
    </document>
    </update-this>
```

I want my final XML to be:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <document name="http://blah">
    <amount>015-39</amount>
    <shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
    <url>http://www.blah.com/my-spade-clothing-11176/487/878765?dn_hhe=mylist-_-nothing-_-nothing-_-nothing</url>

    <size>11.5 D</size>
    <price>100.00 USD</price>
    <stock>present in stock </stock>
    <discounted_price>90 USD</discounted_price>
    <increased_price>110 USD</increased_price>
    <my_id>487</my_id>
    <set_id>878765</set_id>
    </document>
```

This is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="document">
        <xsl:variable name="price" select="substring-before(normalize-space(price),' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currency" select="substring-after(normalize-space(price),' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="difference" select="number($price) * .10"/>

         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <discounted_price><xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($price - $difference,'#,###.00'),' ',$currency)"/></discounted_price>
            <increased_price><xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($price + $difference,'#,###.00'),' ',$currency)"/></increased_price>

        </xsl:copy>


    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="size_present | size_stock">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am suing xslt 1.0 and my xml has multiple document element. Taking the url element, how can I create two new elements `my_id` with the value `487` and `set_id` with the value `878765`?
This is the regex for the url element:

```
^https?://www.blah.com/([a-z-]+-[0-9]+)/[0-9]+/([0-9]+)/?.*
```

Comment: XSLT1.0 does not have support for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, XSLT 1.0 does not have built-in support for regular expressions.

If the url is always going to match a particular format though, you could achieve it with string functions, although it won't be very elegant.

```
<my_id><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(., '//'), '/'), '/'), '/')" /></my_id>
<set_id><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(., '//'), '/'), '/'), '/'), '?')" /></set_id>
```

Although you could avoid some repetition where by using a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="partial" select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(., '//'), '/'), '/')" />
<my_id><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($partial, '/')" /></my_id>
<set_id><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($partial, '/'), '?')" /></set_id>
```

Alternatively, if you processor supports it, you could check out whether you could use the EXSLT extension functions for regular expressions. See http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/index.html